# Is there a image part event handling feature in jquery or jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

[image]

If I have a image like this, can I handle event based on which number or area user clicks?

Example,

If user clicks 1 in this image, it goes to url1.
If user clicks 2 in this image, it goes to url2.

Of course, this is just 1 image.

Is there a feature like this in jquery or jquerymobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use image map:

```
<img src="your img source" width="100" height="100" alt="*alt*" usemap="#yourmap">

<map name="yourmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="firsturl">
  <area shape="rect" coords="50,0,100,50" href="secondurl">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,50,50,100"  href="thirdurl">
  <area shape="rect" coords="50,50,100,100"  href="forth">

</map>
```

If you don't know your image size initially you could calculate the dimensions using JavaScript or jQuery and generate the html in document ready event handler

Comment: Thanks for the fast response :)